# how to create bins using certaing conditions? viz: comparision operators

Tags: pandas

Good day, I need to create bins like 0-30, 30-60,60-90 and 90 above. How can i create a bin for the condition 90 and above. Kindly help.

this is what i have done so far.

```
bins = [0, 30, 60, 90]
group_names = ['Low', 'Okay', 'Good']

categories = pd.cut(df['postTestScore'], bins, labels=group_names)
```

I even tried using query command but not getting the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `np.inf` and parameter `include_lowest=True` for left inclusive first interval:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'postTestScore':[0,25,30,50,60,89,90,100]})
print (df)
   postTestScore
0              0
1             25
2             30
3             50
4             60
5             89
6             90
7            100

bins = [0, 30, 60, 90, np.inf] 
group_names = ['Low', 'Okay', 'Good', 'Best']
categories = pd.cut(df['postTestScore'], bins, labels=group_names, include_lowest=True)
print (categories)
0     Low
1     Low
2     Low
3    Okay
4    Okay
5    Good
6    Good
7    Best
Name: postTestScore, dtype: category
Categories (4, object): [Low < Okay < Good < Best]
```

Comment: one more question. can you please tell me what do we mean by left_inclusive. I am new to this domain.

Comment: It means if 0 (first value of bins) is in first group or not. If omit this parameter and 0 in values it is not in first group, but there is nan.